# Object reflecting unwanted environment

Tags: rendering

I'm seeing a curved environment highlight on the top left + bottom right corners of my object. How can I remove this reflection so my object has consistent lighting?

[image: screenshot of render]

Comment: hello, it's hard to say, maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I'm guessing smooth shading is the problem. Try beveling the edges.

Comment: .. and / or show the wireframe of your box..if the normals are being interpolated across the entire face, it will have a 'curvature' which is not in the geometry.

Comment: @HISEROD that was it - I changed to 'Flat shading' and it fixed the unwanted reflections. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

In the object context menu I changed 'Shade Smooth' to 'Shade Flat' and the unwanted reflections were no longer rendered.